# Deixar paginação fixa usando datatable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, jquery-datatables

Tenho uma tabela e nela estou usando `datatable` do `jQuery`, porém, minha tabela tem muita coluna, e fiz um scroll nela, mas nisso a minha paginação rola junto com o scroll, teria alguma maneira de deixar a paginação fixa?

[**EXEMPLO AQUI**](http://codepen.io/furlann/pen/WbPoYL)

obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para deixar a paginação acima da tabela, basta utilizar a opção [sDOM](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/dom.html) da própria API para regrar que a paginação ficará acima. Desta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable(
      {
        "sDom": '<"top"p>'
      }
    );
});
```

De resto, você estiliza da maneira como quiser.

Comment: _"top"_ não é uma _class_ ou _id_, é uma propriedade, por isso não tem qualquer efeito. Neste [exemplo](http://codepen.io/furlann/pen/WbPoYL), podes ver como se utiliza corretamente o _sDOM_.

Comment: amigão, veja funcionando perfeitamente no exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/iguimaraes/un6aw4at/

Comment: O _scroll_ continua a mover a paginação.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, basta adicionar configurações por CSS, como segue:

```
#myTable_paginate {
    float:left !important;
}
```

Você pode colocar outros ajustes como padding e margin por exemplo, para ajustar melhor

Comment: tipow, teria como deixar a paginação fora do scroll? pra ela ficar fixa

Comment: Aí é com `position: fixed; left:0px; top: 0px;` onde vc vai posicionar o left e top para colocar o div onde você quiser. Mas assim é preciso colocar em algum lugar que não estará sujeito a mudanças por dados variáveis, como no rodapé da tabela. Na parte de cima seria mais seguro.

Answer (score 0):

Para isto, basta definir à partir do próprio *plugin*, utilizando o opção *scoolX*, veja:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
      'scrollX' : true
    });
});
```

---

Para mais informações acerca das funcionalidades que o *plugin* disponibiliza é só seguir as referências.

## Referências:

[Basic initialisation - DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/index.html)

[Scroll - horizontal](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html)